# Iterate over an array and return only matched values?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with JSON and would like to iterate over an array and just return the value I'm looking for. For example, if I have an array of objects and each of those objects has information for a particular book, how can I iterate over each object in that array and only return the one that matches?

I've tried using map, like so (but doesn't work the way I need it to):

```
// books is from my imported JSON object

const favoriteBook = books.map((book) => {
  if (book.title == this.props.params.id) {
    return book;
  }
});

console.log(favoriteBook)
```

However, when I console.log(favoriteBook), I'm seeing an array with one object returned that matches, plus 'undefined' for all the ones that don't match. How can I have it stop as soon as it finds the match and just return that one? Wondering how to do this with 'filter' if possible (?) or a similar way.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for the `.filter()` method, not `.map()`

Comment: Also the value of `this` in that callback won't be the same as it is *outside* the callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose this depends if you want to match multiple books or just a single one.

**Matching Multiple Books**

You can accomplish this via the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, which would handle multiple books :

```
const favoriteBooks = books.filter((b) => { return b.title == this.props.params.id;});
```

**Matching a Single Book**

Otherwise, you likely want the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to return a single one :

```
const favoriteBook = books.find((b) => { return b.title == this.props.params.id;});
```

**Note:** Be extremely mindful of how you use the `this` keyword as it can dramatically change within the context of one of your function calls. You might consider storing it prior to calling the functions or referencing it a different way to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: Correct, but again note the caveat in my comment to the OP about the value of `this` in that callback.

Answer (score 2):

You want `.find` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const favoriteBook = books.find((book) => {
    return book.title == this.props.params.id
}.bind(this)); //.bind for context of 'this'
```

Comment: `.find` will return the first match only. It is useful if you are trying to find a specific object, however, if you need to return multiple objects that matches a criteria, this won't work.
https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/1gm8x6sm/

Comment: @crabbly -- Yep - I assumed `.find` was what OP was looking for since the variable was `favoriteBook`.

Comment: Yea, It wasn't very clear. Trying to search by id, however, the question title says "matched values". @tymeJV

Comment: @crabbly - Damn these mixed signals, description: "only return the one that matches" haha.\

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `.filter()` to get only the items that you want, and after this use `.map()` to get your specific field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const favoriteBook = books.find((book) => (book.title === this.props.params.id));
```